# Creating one database per Client in MySql

Tags: mysql, database, performance, finance

We have a finance related application in which we are creating a database(schema) for each client(Company). There will be many rows for single client.

I want to know if it is best to keep data separate(like it is now) or combine. We are looking for more than 10000 databases per server.

Even though not all users will be online at same time buy 10% of users my be online at same time easily.

My questions are..
1) Is there any serious problem (performance wise) for keeping multiple databases.
2) Is it common practice to keep different databases when it comes to financial data of companies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"10000 databases per server" - that's a lot of databases! [Assuming 5 users per DB, and 10% active that's still 5000 active user connections per server]

Putting that aside: your primary concern here is probably the security of each client's database. Keeping them separate will make it easier to manage security.

To answer your questions:

1. No, there is no performance problem having multiple databases (other than the sheer volume of transactions being handled by the server). In fact, there might be performance gains in terms of row range locks being held.
2. Yes, it is common practice to keep separate databases for financial data. Security, backups are often better handled in per company silos.

Comment: Am I right in saying that it depends on the servers, as to their perfomance? I would agree wih Mitch on this one here though, it depends on how you intend to manage the security, and also how you intend to access them in general, etc.

Comment: Security is handled at application state, and only single user with all permissions is used to access the db. There is only one place where app decides which database to connect, so there is one place where we need to worry about security. And App development is easy as I don't need to worry about other companies data getting selected(in SQL queries). My only concern is how much performance reduction there will be due to large number of connections and databases.